# How to debug woocommerce overridden folder

Tags: debugging, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

I have used woocommerce plugin in my custom wordpress theme but the product variantion is missing from the product page, I'm wondering what am I missing. I have override some of the templates of woocommerce, everything is working fine. just product variation dropdown is missing but additional information section have all the information of product variation.

Is there any way to debug what am I missing

Comment: Check if the variations have a price and and SKU

Comment: Yeah the variation does contains price and sku